# Using mysql with php and ajax, I want to print out a string (rather than a 0/1) for this query

Tags: php, mysql

I apologize if this question has come up before, but I've looked and only found people who are only concerned with the actual result returned by

```
mysql_query($query);
```

I'm making a php/mysql page with ajax for a project where the user can create a database and perform a search by interacting with a few select boxes. I would also like to be able to print out the actual query generated by the php, just for testing.

```
if($dArray[0] == 'sb2a'){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Vehicles WHERE " . $dArray[1] . " = \'" . $dArray[2] + "\'";}
print($sql);
```

It just prints 0 rather than something like

> "SELECT * FROM Vehicles WHERE VID = '01'"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Near the end of your line of code setting the value for `$sql`:

```
. $dArray[2] + "\'";
```

That `+` should be a `.`

Comment: Thanks! I had reasoned that I was using the wrong function rather than making a simple mistake in syntax lol.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($dArray[0] == 'sb2a')
{
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM Vehicles WHERE " . $dArray[1] . " = \'" . $dArray[2] . "\'";
}
print($sql);
```

To concatenation we should always use '.'

Answer (score 0):

Query should be like this.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Vehicles WHERE {$dArray[1]}  = '{$dArray[2]}'";
```